# Is the answer command slow on iOS?

Tags: livecode

I have written an app that uses the `answer` command.  This seems to run well until it is deployed to the iPad or simulator where there is a discernible delay when I choose either of the responses on the answer.

I am using Livecode version 6.5.1 and deploying to iOS 7

my code says :

```
    answer question "Hooray !!! you have finished..." with "Play again" or "go back" titled "Game over"
    go card "Category Page"
```

there is a noticeable delay between responding to the `answer question` prompt and the next card being displayed.  If I take out the answer statement, then the next card is displayed immediately.

(PS I realise this code doesn't show what action to take for each option - I have commented that out at the moment to try to isolate the problem)

Comment: Please give an example of your code

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be slow. If the problem persists I would report it as a bug. 6.5.2 was released a few days ago so give that a try first:

http://downloads.livecode.com/livecode/

If the problem persists report the issue here:

http://quality.runrev.com

Answer (score 0):

To my experience, the answer command isn't slow on mobile devices. So far, the only device that caused me serious problems with the answer command was the Sony Vaio, if the answer command is preceded by a beep.

You may have a script somewhere, which executes right before or after the next card opens.

A quick wat to test this is

```
on someHandler // openCard or whatever this may be in your own script
  answer question "Hooray !!! you have finished..." with "Play again" or "go back" titled "Game over"
  lock messages
  go card "Category Page"
  unlock messages
end someHandler
```

If your handler starts with a lock screen, the next card won't be drawn until the handler finishes. E.g.

```
on someHandler
  lock screen
  answer "something"
  go next cd
  // do a lot of stuff here
end someHandler
```

may cause a long delay.

Also, going to a card directly after executing the answer command without using e.g. `get the result` or an if statement may cause problems occasionally. I have had cases where the script continues to run till the end of the handler while the answer window was on screen.

Another problem could be that you are actually going to the card of another stack or running the syntax in a (pre)OpenCard, (pre)OpenStack or other (pre)Open* handler. If you do this, the card may not render until the (pre)Open* handler has finished running. You can solve this with a construction like

```
on openStack
  send "initiateStack" to me in 0 millisecs
end openStack

on initiateStack
  // put everything here that doesn't need to be
  // done before the card is visible, e.g. setting
  // fields and checkboxes on other cards, reading
  // user preferences etc.
end initiateStack
```

So far just a number of possibilities. If you can provide more details, e.g. the actual code of your stack, I'll update my answer as necessary.